# CDI管理BeanのメソッドをJAX-RSで実行したい

Tags: java-ee, jax-rs

a.xhtml管理BeanであるABeanのhoge()メソッドをJAX-RSを使用したリクエストで行いたいです。この場合、a.xhmlのh:linkのoutcomeにはどのようなパスを記述すればよいでしょうか？

・ABean.java

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
@Path("abean")
public ABean{
   @GET
   @Path("hoge")
   public void hoge(){
      System.out.println("hoge!");
   }
}
```

・a.xhtml

```
<h:link outcome="?" value="HOGE"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`h:link`コンポーネントのoutcomeでは実現できないので、`h:outputLink`コンポーネントにしてみてはどうでしょうか？

```
<h:outputLink value="[RESTFul URL]">HOGE</h:outputLink>
```